# What does this rule mean?

Tags: exponentiation

I read this rule in a book .it says,
If $a>0$, $a$ is not equal to $1$ and $a^x=a^y$,then $x=y$.
But I don't understand why the value of $a$ has to be greater than $0$.
What  if  the value of $a$ was less than $0$?
Wouldn't it be the same ?For example,
 if $a=-2$,
for which other value of $x$,could I get $4$ other than $2$?

Comment: You don't define a real exponential function $a^x$ for $a<0$. Just imagine the domain of that!!

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean to say? I am new to these rules.Thanks

Comment: Ok! Using your own terms: what is the domain of $a^x$ where $a=-2$? Can you tell?

Comment: A silly example as well, $(-1)^1 = (-1)^3$ despite $1\neq 3$.  Of course, you could change your statement to say $|a|$ is not equal to $1$ to cover this case.  That said, even if you can't find another $y$ such that $(-2)^2 = (-2)^y$ that doesn't imply that for *all* $x,y$ if $(-2)^x=(-2)^y$ that it would imply $x=y$.  Consider what happens when you start using fractions in the exponent instead.

Comment: Could please give an example of what you mentioned in the last sentences?

Answer (score 1):

When $a<0$ exponentiation is not well defined for $x \in \mathbb R$.

Note that for $a>0$, $a\neq 1$ the equality $x=y$ from $a^x=a^y$ holds since $f(x)=a^x$ is injective.

Comment: Provided $a\neq1$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Yes of course! I add that. Thanks